# Commands button not working on iOS build

Tags: codenameone

I use codenameone to build android and javascript apps for many years. This is the first time I sending build to iOS. The apps is install on my device, everythings is working fine, just the Commands (on the Old GUI Form) not working when pressed (touch). This happen on every Forms (design using Old GUI Editor)

It this a iOS Build Server error(I don't think so)..

Anyone can help on this?

Comment: Is it working in the iOS simulator? Are you libraries, plugin and skins up to date? Can you give screenshots/code that isn't working? In the theme constants do you define a command behavior? Are you using the global toolbar? Did you define a setting for the on-top toolbar? (both would normally be in the `init(Object)` method of your main class

Comment: You are right, I forget to test on iOS simulator. 
After test, it is NOT working as on the real device. No response.
Every Commands across all forms (Created using old GUI designer) is not working. No any definition in Theme constants. No any setting to the on top toolbar, my init(Object) is doing nothing.

Comment: After I test around, I found this happen if I am using native theme.. I change to other theme, the commands works fine.. but I have to readjust all my forms :(

Comment: This might be related to work we did with the command behavior where we overhauled the look of the side menu and other features. We tried to be as compatible as possible but it's pretty hard to test every functionality or behavior.

Comment: Sure, understand. I choice to use another theme as solution to solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: After I use the create a new theme, I found the compiler ask me to remove "commandBehavior".. after I remove, the commands button have change from Side menu (slide out) to bottom again, which same as native themes. After then, the commands not working again... :( Can you advice what should I do? remove all commands and create them as Button component?

Comment: I tried to add   Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true);
  Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true); in the main class init(Obj) function, after then I can show that SideMenu appear and Commands are inside it, but they are not responsive after click. Didi I missed something?   As long as the "commandBehavior" not removed from theme, evethings work fine...

Comment: How are you handling the command actions? You are using the old GUI builder right? How did you add/process the events?

Comment: I use the Old GUI Editor, Select Form, Select Commands from the Properties, Select partivular commands, then click the "Go to source", will jump to the particular function (Overide, protected function).. this commands is works under android, simulator, android devices for years. Just on the iOS simulator, after remove the commandBehavior, its fails on iOS simulator.